# How can I play an audio source while a key is being held down?

Tags: unity, c#

```
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A))
        {
            audioSource.Play();
        }
```

Except this only functions once as the key is held down. Same goes with GetKeyDown. Is there any way I can get this to loop as long as they key is being held down? (Is in Update)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Input.GetKeyDown`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetKeyDown.html) is true on the frame when the player started pressing the key and  [`Input.GetKeyUp`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetKeyUp.html) on the frame when it is released. So all you need to do is call audioSource.Play on GetKeyDown and then AudioSource.Stop on GetKeyUp:

```
if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.A)){
    audioSource.Play();
}
if (Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.A)){
    audioSource.Stop();
}
```

Note that Stop will reset the audio clip to the beginning. There are also cases where you just want to pause the audio clip and then later resume it later at the same point. In that case use [Pause](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AudioSource.Pause.html) and [UnPause](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AudioSource.UnPause.html) instead of Stop and Play.